# $3\times 2^m + 4 = n^2$

Tags: contest-math, arithmetic

I have been trying to solve this problem but I couldn't find any way to find the answers. Find all natural numbers m and n such that:
$3\times\ 2^m + 4 = n^2$
This is a question from the Moroccan Maths Olympiad (2019.)

I tried bringing $4$ to the other side and factorising to get: $3\times 2^m=(n+2)(n−2),$ and I tried solving for that $n+2$ is a multiple of three then $n-2$ is a multiple of three but I couldn't find anything.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You need to provide: 1. source of the problem 2. your own efforts/thoughts 3. other details and clarifications, such as whether $m, n$ are supposed to be integers.

Comment: Any time you have a difference of squares you should try factoring it.

Comment: @WhatsUp this is a problem from a Moroccan Maths Olympiad, I tried brining 4 to the other side and factorising to get: $3 \times\ 2^m = (n+2)(n-2)$ and I tried solving for that n+2 is a multiple of three then n-2 is a mulltiple of three but I couldn't find anything

Comment: @mathsloverrr713 Which year? It's our policy not to help out with current contest questions (though past contest questions are fine).

Comment: @TheoBendit 2019, it was passed on Friday, November 22nd 2019, it was in the first level of the first baccaluréate year.

Comment: Good! Have a +1 from me. As a final step (so that your question isn't closed), you should put your efforts and the source (including the year) into the body of your question. People reviewing questions don't always check the comments.

Comment: @mathsloverrr713 Don't post that in a comment. Edit your question to improve it. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: @mathsloverrr713 add the information to the question. Comments are n9t part of the question.

Comment: @TheoBendit done! thank you

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Why did you delete your answer? It was a good answer to an (at least) adequate question.

Comment: I’ve been in trouble recently for answering inadequate questions, and while I think this is an adequate question, as long as it is closed, I figure better to avoid another multi day ban. @TheoBendit

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Dark times at MSE. :-(

Comment: @mathsloverrr713 Please avoid math-only titles. See [Guidelines for good use of MathJax on question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$. From the equation, you can deduce that $$2 \mid n^2 \implies 2 \mid n\implies n = 2k \implies 3\cdot 2^m + 4 = 4k^2\quad(1)$$ Observe that $m = 1$ yields no integer solution, and $m = 2 \implies k = 2 \implies n = 4$.Thus consider $m \ge 3$, divide both sides of $(1)$  by $4$, you have: $3\cdot 2^{m-2}+1=k^2\implies k$ is odd $$\implies k = 2q+1\implies 3\cdot2^{m-2}+1=(2q+1)^2 \implies 3\cdot2^{m-2} = 4q(q+1)\quad(2)$$ Observe also that $m = 3,4$ yields no integer solution in $q$. So $m \ge 5$, and $(2)$ gives $$3\cdot 2^{m-4} = q(q+1)$$ $$\implies q =2, q+1 = 3 \implies q =2^{m-4}$$ $$\implies q =3, q+1 = 4 =2^{m-4}$$ $$\implies m =5\implies k = 5\implies n = 10 \implies (m,n) = (5,10)$$ $$\implies m =6\implies k = 7\implies n = 14 \implies (m,n) = (6,14)$$ are the remaining solutions. So altogether, the solutions are: $(2,4), (5,10), (6,14)$ are the $3$ solutions and they are the only solutions to the equation.

Comment: Your answer is not completely correct because $m = 5, n =10$ also is a solution

Comment: why isn't $(m,n) = (2,4) $ a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Either $$n+2=3\cdot 2^i,n-2=2^j$$ or $$n+2=2^i, n-2=3\cdot 2^j$$ for some $i,j\geq 0.$

So you want to solve:

$$4=3\cdot 2^i-2^j\tag 1$$
and:
$$4=2^i-3\cdot 2^j.\tag2$$

I’ll partially solve $(1)$ for you.

If $3\cdot 2^i-2^j>0,$ then $j\leq i+1.$

Then $$4=3\cdot 2^i-2^j\geq 3\cdot 2^i-2^{i+1}=2^i.$$

So $i\leq 2.$ This let’s you just check individual cases.

A similar argument works for $(2).$ Find a bound on $j$ in terms of $i,$ find the minimum possible value for the difference, and get an upper bound on $i.$

You should get three answers, total.

Answer (score 0):

$$3\cdot2^{m} + 4 = n^2$$

We take the three cases $m=3a, m=3a+1,$ and $m=3a+2.$
The problem can be reduced to finding the integer points on elliptic curves as follows.

$\bullet m=3a$
Let $X = 3\cdot2^a, Y=3n$, then we get  $Y^2 =X^3 + 36.$
According to [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/972/a/2), this elliptic curve has $(X,Y)=(-3,\pm 3)$, $(0,\pm 6)$, $(4,\pm 10)$, $(12,\pm 42).$
Hence $(X,Y)= (12, 42)  \implies (m,n)=(6,14).$

$\bullet m=3a+1$
Let $X = 6\cdot2^a, Y=6n$, then we get $Y^2 =X^3 + 144.$
This elliptic curve has $(X,Y)=(0,12)$, then there is no natural solution $(m,n).$

$\bullet m=3a+2$
Let $X = 12\cdot2^a, Y=12n$, then we get    $Y^2 =X^3 + 576.$
This elliptic curve has $(X,Y)=(-8 , 8 ), (0 , 24 ), (12 , 48 ), (24 , 120 ), (160 , 2024 ).$
Hence $(X,Y)= (12 , 48)  \implies (m,n)=(2,4).$
$(X,Y)= (24 , 120)  \implies (m,n)=(5,10).$

Thus, there are only natual solutions $(m,n)=(2,4),(5,10),(6,14).$